# Report Viewer showing blank for particular report file (rdlc) on Staging Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have implemented rdlc (2005) Report in my asp.net project.

Report shows data from sql server database.

this report is showing through ASP.Net Report Viewer.

We have 2 servers , problem is report is working fine on first server and it shows Blank report viewer on another server.

I have checked all the configuration is correct and also restored the database on first server and found it is running there.

We have many other reports already deployed and they work fine on both the server, so I am sure that this is not a problem of report viewer or my code.

I searched for this problem but people have this problem for all the reports whereas I have it only for one report.

[image]

Working report on another server.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by 2 servers?
Two database servers (where the reporting server BDs are?), 2 web servers (where your web application is) or 2 reporting services on a web farm?

Comment: everything, I mean I have stagging and production server. They both have seperate web server, sql server and reporting services

Comment: humm...it would be very hard to help this way them. You have to check everything on the flow from the report to the DB. I suggest starting with the data sources.

Comment: but I wonder how other reports are working fine, if there is an issue with reporting service or report viewer or sql server it should not work for all

Comment: do all the reports share the same datasource? Any chance the report's datasource is embed?

Comment: reports having different datasources but all are derived from one base class, no embeded.